# saving mathml rendered to html5 canvas as png

Tags: html, canvas, png, mathml

My ultimate goal is to save rendered presentation MathML to a .PNG file. Knowing just enough about programming to be dangerous :-) there may be a better way to do this...I am drawing the equation on a canvas element, then trying to save the canvas element as a .PNG. I started with code found here -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas -- and modified as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
        "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'     style='fontsize:40px'>" +
        "<math>" +
        "<mtable>" +
        "<mtr>" +
        "<mtd columnalign='right'>" +
            "<mn>2</mn>" +
            "<mi>x</mi>" +
            "<mo>+</mo>" +
            "<mn>3</mn>" +
            "<mo>&#8722;</mo>" +
            "<mn>3</mn>" +
         "</mtd>" +
         "<mtd columnalign='center'> " +              
            "<mo>=</mo>" +
        "</mtd>" +
        "<mtd columnalign='left'> " +              
            "<mn>9</mn>" +
            "<mo>&#8722;</mo>" +
            "<mn>3</mn>" +
         "</mtd>" +
        "</mtr>" +
        "</mtable>" +
        "</math>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</foreignObject>" +
        "</svg>";

var svg = new (self.BlobBuilder || self.MozBlobBuilder || self.WebKitBlobBuilder);
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
svg.append(data);
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg.getBlob("image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"));
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;

window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the window.open I can see the MathML in the canvas element, but the .PNG generated by the toDataURL is just transparent (no math equations). What am I missing? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat the issue I see is that you defer the rendering of the canvas until the image loads, but you call `window.open` in the code without making sure its loaded. You would need to do something like the following

```
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    // now the image has been drawn for sure *before* opening the window
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
};
img.src = url;
```

Comment: Looks like its happening on the toDataURL...maybe the canvas is "dirty" after all...